# Linking between tables in Numbers

Tags: icloud, numbers, iwork

I have a table in numbers, and I want a cell to equal the value of a cell in a different table. Following the advice of [this Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5738689), I tried

```
=Units Sold::B2
```

, with Units Sold being the table with the value I wanted, and B2 being the value I wanted in the table "Units Sold".

[image]

To clarify, I want D2 of "Juice and Beverages" to equal the value of B2 of "Units Sold".

What am I doing wrong? Numbers for iCloud gives the error

> The formula contains an invalid reference.

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax is correctly formatted, maybe you have formatted the cell to something. Once you start typing the table title it should auto populate after `=`

Comment: @soulshined OK. If that is the case, how can I make it work?

Comment: Format your cell to 'Automatic' then proceed like normal. Type `=` then start typing `Units Sold::B2` it should work. Or do what grgarside has displayed

Comment: @soulshined Both cells are formatted to automatic, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try ⌘+Q and reopen Numbers and try again, there's nothing wrong with the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work in iCloud Numbers:

Select the cell you want the result in: i.e  **D2 of "Juice and Beverages"**

And then in the text field at the top of the page enter:

```
=SUM('Units Sold' :: B2)
```

Take note of difference in how I have written it and how you did. Which was you main problem.

[image]

---

When done, click the green tick button on the right. And you will see this as the end result.

[image]

---

You can see some documentation on some of the included Functions by clicking into a cell and then into the:

1, text filed above:

2, you can search for a formula.

3,insert a Function template into the text field.

4, see a description of the Function and scrolling down further in the description you will see examples.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Cross-table referencing is not currently possible in Numbers in iCloud.com.

In OS X, if typing doesn't work, simply press = then click the cell that you want to reference.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not working - the cursor just appears in the cell I am trying to select.

Comment: @rocket101 You need to be in formula edit mode to click-select cell references. Make sure the formula edit bar is active. Alternatively, type the reference (see the left animation).

Comment: It doesn't work in formula edit mode, the same thing happens. Bug?

Comment: @rocket101 This sounds like a bug then. Try it with a new spreadsheet to see if it's the spreadsheet. Do you have the latest version of Numbers?

Comment: @I am using numbers in iCloud

Comment: @rocket101 Ah! That's not possible yet—I've edited my answer.

Comment: @grgarside it does work. See my answer

Comment: @markhunte That's a nice workaround! Not exactly linking a cell though (it won't work for text for example).

Comment: Interesting that clicking in another table doesn't work in iCloud numbers on my Mac, but does on my iPad.